# Loading CSS via Theme and use replica id in url

Tags: xpages

We are always using replica ids in urls when accessing xpages.

```
_http://myserver/C1257B76006B7CF2/index.xsp  
Good / bad behavior?
```

when I load my css via a theme, I get the source HTML:

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/C1257B76006B7CF2/xsp/mystyle.css" >
```

The thing is that "/xsp" is appended after the replica ID.
This does not happen if you have an url like

```
_http://myserver/database.nsf/index.xsp
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/database.nsf/mystyle.css">
```

All this is working in Domino 8.5.3.
The 8.5.3 server seems to understand "/xsp"

After upgrading to Domino 9 the stylesheet is not loaded.
The server could not find design note ....
Domino 9 seems to not understand "/xsp"

```
 _http://myserver/__C1257B76006B7CF2.nsf/index.xsp
```

this url loads the stylsheet in Domino 9 but does not work in 8.5.3

Anyone using themes and replica ids as urls in Domino 9 with success?

Comment: Are these stylesheets stored in a database external to the one containing the theme?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635494/server-independent-reference-in-an-xpages-theme

Comment: You are asking multiple questions. I would suggest you separate these out.

Comment: I personally tend to avoid replica IDs. If they're hard-coded you can't separate multiple environments (dev / test/ prod). If they're in keyword documents, it's hard to tell from just looking at them whether they're right or wrong and where to find the database they refer to quickly. I'm not aware of a performance hit using database paths instead of replica IDs. So for support and migration reasons, I tend to prefer database paths and ensure databases are installed in the same location on replica servers.