# jQuery plugin DataTables does not initialize in XPINC

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xpages

I am trying to get the jQuery plugin "DataTables" working in XPINC but have not found a way for that.

These resources are included into the applications "Web-Content"-Folder:

```
<xp:script src="jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" clientSide="true"/>
<xp:script src="jquery/plugins/DataTables/dataTables.js" type="text/javascript" clientSide="true"/>
```

When viewing in a browser everything works fine.

But the initialisation of the DataTable-plugin is not passing in XPINC.
If I manually try to find out if $.fn.dataTables exists, the browsers shows me an [object] while XPINC returns "undefined".

Has anyone else tried this plugin and finally got it working for browser and XPINC?

Comment: Try to leave out the /*.nsf part of your link as the context root is always the database itself, e.g. "jquery/..."

Comment: I edited the lines with the script and entered the source as it is in the XPage. Once again. This is working in every browser but *not* in the Notes Client. Is there anyone else who need to have jQuery plugins working on both sides (browser/Notes Client)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635494/server-independent-reference-in-an-xpages-theme

Comment: Finally I got this thing working by following the instructions given [here](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1216). In order to have the jQuery plugin working you **need** to include the script and css files as a part of the document header (not as plain resources).#

Comment: Nice! Please, rephrase your solution as Answer.

Comment: @PantelisBotsas I second Frantisek, answer your own question in the answer block below including the sample code. Closes the question, can be upvoted and adds to your repudiation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got this thing working by following the instructions given [here](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1216). In order to have the jQuery plugin working you need to include the script and css files as a part of the document header (not as plain resources).